# React Native - text input não perde o foco

Tags: react-native, input, text, onblur

Coloquei um `<TextInput/>` para fazer a ação de busca no meu projeto, mas depois que eu clico nesse `<TextInput/>`, o foco não sai mais dele, não importa onde clique na tela, a função `onBlur()` sequer é executada e não apresenta nenhum erro, mesmo se eu for para outra página e voltar para a tela que tem esse `<TextInput/>`, aquela barrinha que fica piscando quando vamos digitar, continua piscando, já tentei busquei por vários exemplos de `<TextInput/>` e todos apresentam esse mesmo problema, deve ser algo muito bobo, mas eu não consigo resolver de jeito nenhum. Aqui está o código que estou testando agora.

````
import {
  StatusBar,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  SafeAreaView,
} from 'react-native';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      borderColor: '#fff',
    };
  }

  onFocus() {
    this.setState({
      borderColor: '#000',
    });
  }

  onBlur() {
    this.setState({
      borderColor: '#fff',
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          height: '100%',
          backgroundColor: '#363A44',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <StatusBar
          barStyle="light-content"
          hidden={false}
          backgroundColor="#000"
        />
        <TextInput
          onBlur={() => this.onBlur()}
          onFocus={() => this.onFocus()}
          style={{
            height: 40,
            width: 100,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: this.state.borderColor,
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;```
````

Comment: Não esta a ocorrer erro algum, como você diz, nesse código. https://snack.expo.io/@sant0will/a2e726

Comment: Abra esse link que vc me mandou e coloque para rodar no Android, clique no `TextInput` e depois tente clicar fora dele.

Comment: certo certo, entendi

Answer (score 0):

O seu problema é recorrente no React Native, ele acontece basicamente por que a View não consegue detectar os toques na tela. Como alternativa, você poderá trocar sua View master por uma ScrollView configurada para aceitar os toques na tela.

Baiscamente basta alterar:

```
<View
    style={{
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      backgroundColor: '#363A44',
      alignItems: 'center',
    }}>
    <StatusBar
      barStyle="light-content"
      hidden={false}
      backgroundColor="#000"
    />
    <TextInput
      onBlur={() => this.onBlur()}
      onFocus={() => this.onFocus()}
      style={{
        height: 40,
        width: 100,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: this.state.borderColor,
      }}
    />
</View>
```

Por:

```
<ScrollView
    style={{
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      backgroundColor: '#363A44',
      alignItems: 'center',
    }}
    scrollEnabled={false}
    keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'>
    <StatusBar
      barStyle="light-content"
      hidden={false}
      backgroundColor="#000"
    />
    <TextInput
      onBlur={() => this.onBlur()}
      onFocus={() => this.onFocus()}
      style={{
        height: 40,
        width: 100,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: this.state.borderColor,
      }}
    />
</ScrollView>
```

[scrollEnabled](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#scrollenabled): Deixa a view estatica, sem o scroll.

[keyboardShouldPersistTaps](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#keyboardshouldpersisttaps): Habilita a possibilidade de tocar a área fora do teclado.

[Exemplo funcionando](https://snack.expo.io/@sant0will/vigorous-french-fries)

Comment: Entendi, eu coloquei o `<ScrollView/>` mas ai o problema foi que eu precisei usar um `<MapView/>` e dentro do `<ScrollView/>` ele não funcionava, ai eu consegui resolver com `<TouchableWithoutFeedback/>`, valeu pela ajuda.